# Cannot load mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I've already seen [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834421/error-when-trying-to-install-app-with-mysql2-gem) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470903/i-cannot-load-my-mysql2-gem) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835912/rails-specified-mysql2-for-database-adapter-but-the-gem-is-not-loaded?rq=1), but none of these helped me...

This is the trick: I have to fix this **without** touching the Gemfile. I'm currently creating my working environment so that it matches the production server, so, I cannot modify the rails' code at all.

My OS: OSX 10.11

Ruby: ruby 2.0.0p643

Rails: 4.0.0

The gem is the Gemfile as `gem 'mysql2'`. There are no errors when doing `bundle install`, but when I try to `rake db:migrate --trace` this is the output:

> ```
> rake aborted!
> There was an error while trying to load the gem 'mysql2'.
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
> /Users/redar/redar/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
> /Users/redar/redar/Rakefile:4:in `require'
> /Users/redar/redar/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/rake:23:in `load'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
> /Users/redar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
> ```

I don't know how to interpret this. Is there something wrong with the `Rakefile`?

Also, this is the [output from the mkmf.log](http://pastebin.com/e6CfCy9r)

---

**EDIT:** This is the content of my Rakefile, located at myapp/folder

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

MyApp::Application.load_tasks
```

Comment: I assume you have mysql installed in your system, right? (brew install mysql)

Comment: Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21544 , you might want to try "gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'" in your gemfile

Comment: I cannot modify the existing Gemfile; as described above, I'm trying to emulate the production server.

Comment: Well, is the Gemfile.lock exactly the same as the one in your production environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This will make sure that you are executing "rake db:migrate" with the gems listed in the Gemfile loaded and available.  If you run it without "bundle exec" you may be executing only with the system gems available.